# A Script That is Aware of Remote File Change

Tags: bash, curl

`curl -z pci.ids --remote-time --silent -f -L -O \ http://pciids.sourceforge.net/v2.2/pci.ids`

This command checks if the remote file changed and downloads only if the remote file has been modified. How can I make it display "Changed" only if the file has changed?

Comment: Should be on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Curl, wget and a few others use the "last modified" date. The "last modified" date in http doesn't necessarily correspond to anything on the physical file.  You will need to download the file and check to see if it's changed.